# Why is my condition causing my while loop to become infinite?

Tags: python

The question I am asking the user, is to input their total bill as an integer greater than zero and less than or equal to 2000. While the user's entry is not in the specified range I will continue to ask them for input.

After that, I wanted to ask the user to enter the size of their dinner party as an integer greater than zero and less than or equal to 20, following the same rule as mentioned above. If I can have guidance with the first part of my program, I am confident I can finish the rest on my own. This what I have so far:

```
bill = int(input('What is the bill total: '))
while bill > 0 and bill <= 2000 :
    bill = int(input('What is the bill total: '))
```

Answer (score 3):

You got your condition reversed.  Negate it:

```
bill = int(input('What is the bill total: '))
while bill <= 0 or bill > 2000 :
    print "Total must be positive and no more than 2000"
    bill = int(input('What is the bill total: '))
```

... or, if you prefer the concept "while input is not legal", just stuff **not** around the whole thing:

```
bill = int(input('What is the bill total: '))
while not (bill > 0 and bill <= 2000) :
    print "Total must be positive and no more than 2000"
    bill = int(input('What is the bill total: '))
```

Comment: You're welcome.  This is a basic technique, an early one in classes I teach.  Please remember to accept an answer, even if you have to write it yourself.  That and voting on answers and comments helps keep Stack Overflow running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you want the bill to be more than 0 and less than 2000, and the party size needs to be more than 0 and less than 20, use this:

```
while True:
    bill = int(input('What is the bill total: '))
    while bill > 0 and bill <= 2000:
        size = int(input('What is the party size: '))
        while size > 0 and size <= 20:
            #do stuff
            break
        break
    break
```